# Returning Promises from Config File in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

As Title suggest I have a use case where my config file calls out external service to fetch the data and returns the data to caller. I am having a problem that config file only reads the data from external source while application starts up and for every real time update I have to restart the server which is not feasible, Below is the code

Config File

```
let Config = {}
let configMap = ExternalService.getData("key").then((data)=>{

Config.message = data

return Config
}
export default configMap
```

index.js of Module

```
import configfetcher    from "./config.ts";

export let ConfigMap = {
  ["DEFAULT"]: {
    ["V2"]: configfetcher
  }
},
```

Caller Function

```
import {ConfigMap} from './Module'

let getValue = (key:string) => {

let configValuePromise = ConfigMap["DEFAULT"][key];

return Promise.resolve(configValuePromise).then((config) => {
return config
}
```

Comment: as I understand it it should be `configValuePromise().then(...)`

Comment: configValuePromise already comes as resolved here thats the issue that all the async calls in config should happen again when i hit the caller function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you take a look in to https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await
On the side note: What you can do is fetching the config from the, what you have named here as "Caller Function". If you know that your config is asynch, wait for it.

Comment: the nodejs version used does not support top level await hence this approach